# Find all rings $R$ satisfying $\mathbb Z \subset R \subset \mathbb Z[\frac {1}{2}]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Find all rings $R$ satisfying $\mathbb Z \subset R \subset \mathbb Z[\frac {1}{2}]$.

**Solution:** Let $f \in R$. Then $f= \frac {m}{2^n}$ for some integers $m,n$.  Since $2^{n-1} \in R$, hence $\frac {m}{2} \in R$. Hence one gets that $ \frac {1}{2} \in R$, so $R=\mathbb Z[\frac {1}{2}]$, so there is no ring $R$ satisfying given conditions.

> What are the other possible solutions of this problem?

P.S: You can give a solution using any theorem from commutative algebra also.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}[3/4]$?

Comment: @Mr.Chip $3/4\in R$ implies $2\cdot(3/4) = 3/2\in R$ which implies $1/2 = 3/2 -1\in R$.

Comment: Part deux: Describe the elements of $\Bbb{Z}[1/6]$ and find all the rings $R$ satisfying $\Bbb{Z}\subset R\subset \Bbb{Z}[1/6]$. Generalize to your heart's content!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/set-of-prime-numbers-and-subrings-of-the-rationals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subrings $\,R\subseteq \Bbb Q$ [are characterized](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1242469/242) by the subset of $S$ of primes that become invertible in $\,R,\,$ i.e. $\,R = \Bbb Z[1/p\ :\ p\in S]$ is obtained by adjoining the inverses of all primes in $S$. One easily checks that this is a ring since fractions having denominators being products of such primes are closed under addition and multiplication.

Conversely, let $\,R\,$ be such a proper subring $\,\Bbb Z\subsetneq R\subset \Bbb Q,\,$ and let $\,r = a/b\in R\,$ be a noninteger. Wlog $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ so by Bezout $\,aj+bk = 1\,$ for some $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Thus $\,j(a/b) + k = 1/b\in R.\,$ Hence $\,a/b\in R\iff 1/b\in R,\,$ so $R$ is generated by adjoining inverses of integers to $\,\Bbb Z.\,$ But $n$ is invertible iff all its prime factors are invertible, so  we can restrict to inverses of primes.

**Remark** $\ $ The above generalizes to any Bezout domain, i.e. rings like $\,\Bbb Z\,$ where gcds enjoy a Bezout identity. Said in the language of commutative algebra, every overring (of fractions) of a Bezout domain is a localization, i.e. is generated by adjoining inverses of elements.  [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194719/242) for further discussion, including literature references.

Note: we eliminate Bezout by instead using Euclid: $\,(a,b) = 1,\ b\mid a\,\Rightarrow\, b\mid 1,\,$ i.e. $\,1/b\in R.$