# $a,b$ co-prime elements in PID $R$ , then to show $R[X]/(aX-b) \cong R[1/a]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, localization

Let $R$ be a PID , let $a,b \in R$ be co-prime elements , i.e. $aR+bR=R$ . Then obviously $R[X]/(aX-b)$ is an integral domain  . How to show that $R[X]/(aX-b) \cong R[1/a]$ ?

Comment: From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798783/121097) we learn that $R[X]/(aX-b) \simeq R[b/a]$. But in your case $R[b/a]=R[1/a]$.

Comment: Every overring $E$ of fractions of a $\rm\color{#c00}{Bezout}$ domain is a localization because $\,b/a\in E\,\Rightarrow\, 1/a\in E,\,$ which follows by dividing $\ \color{#c00}{a j+ b k = 1}\ $ by $\,a.\,$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389251/242) for more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $a,b$ is an $R$-sequence, then $ax-b$ is prime (Eisenbud, Exercise 10.4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798439/if-a-b-is-an-r-sequence-then-ax-b-is-prime-eisenbud-exercise-10-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider a *Bézout's relation*: $\;ua+vb=1,\quad (u,v\in R)$. In  $R[1/a]$, you have:
$$\frac 1a=u+\frac{vb}a.$$

Comment: Okay ... but I am still not getting it ... how to get a surjective homomorphism from $R[X] \to R[1/a]$ with kernel $(aX-b)$ ? Or are you suggesting any other method ..?

Comment: You map $X$ to $b/a$,thus defining a homomorphism from $\mathbf R[X]$ to $R[1/a]$. As $aX-b$ lies in the kernel, it passes to the quotient $R[X]/(aX-b)$, and it's surjective because of the relation I mention in my answer.

Comment: Ok I get that now ... and why is the kernel exactly $(aX-b)$ ?

Comment: It's not hard to see it's a prime ideal. If the kernel strictly contained the ideal $(aX-b)$, it would be a maximal ideal of $R[X]$, which would have a non-zero intersection $R$, and the canonical  morphism $R\to R[1/a]$ would not be injective.

Comment: @Bernard You are using too much that $R$ is a PID in a question that obviously holds in a more general context.

Comment: @user26857: Well, Bézout makes things easier…

Comment: @Bernard I won't be so sure, at least not when it comes to show that the ideal $(aX-b)$ is prime.

Comment: Oh! this point… Yes, I use the fact the structure of prime ideals in a polynomial ring over a P.I.D. is known.