# How to precisely define $b/a$ if $a \mid b$ in a general commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $a,b \in R$. Suppose that $a \mid b$, which means that there exists some $k \in R$ such that $k\cdot a = b$. I now often see expressions of the form $b/a$ in this context. ( For example the important lcm-gcd-formula $gcd(a,b) = ab / lcm(a,b)$ ). My question:

> Is it enough to simply define $b/a := k$ or are there some caveats? (I think one problem here might be that $b/a$ does not have to be unique with this naive definition.)

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)

Comment: If $R$ is not an integral domain, then yes this can be an issue. However, if it is an integral domain, then $k$ is unique (assuming $a \not= 0$). Can you prove this for yourself?

Comment: @aidangallagher4 Beware that overrings of fractions need not be localizations. That is true [only for Bezout domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389251/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $[a, b] = ab / (a, b)$, the quotient exists in GCD domain and is unique.

For an arbitrary commutative ring, it's possible to define 'quotient', see [**Localization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)).